# Is there a faster alternative to Aho-Corasick when searching for any occurrence rather than all occurrences of each of the substrings?

Tags: strings, search-trees, substrings

Aho-Corasick can result in a quadratic number of matches because it finds all occurrences of each searched-for substring. What is a faster algorithm or modification to this one to simply determine if there is any occurrence for each of the substrings?

Comment: What if you abort processing when a match is found ?